# Буква Л в словах кристаллический и кристальный

Tags: словообразование

Почему в слове "кристаллический" пишется две буквы Л, а в слове "кристальный" одна?

Answer (score 2):

Дело, по всей видимости в том, что к тому времени,  когда слово "кристалл" стало писаться с двумя "л" ( у Ушакова в1935 возможно написание и с одной "л") "кристальный" с ним был связан, практически только с точки зрения этимологии.

Слово "кристальный" раньше основным значением имело, относящийся к кристаллу. Слово успело приобрести ещё дополнительный смысл "чистый, прозрачный", но в основном значении было вытеснено словом "кристаллический". Так как к тому времени, когда кристалл стали писать только с удвоенными согласными, "кристальный" практически выпал из гнезда данного слова, то удвоенных букв в нём и не оказалось.

Answer (score 2):

ПРАВИЛА УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ БУКВ   »»   Правописание согласных  »»   Двойные согласные  »»   Двойные согласные в заимствованных (иноязычных) корнях и суффиксах

§ 109. В словах, образованных от основ, оканчивающихся на две одинаковые согласные, двойные согласные перед суффиксами сохраняются, напр.: группа — группка, групповой, группировать; программа — программка, программный, программировать; балл — пятибалльный, галлы — галльский, металл — металлический, металлург; класс — классовый, классный, одноклассник; компромисс — компромиссный, киловатт — кило-ваттный, либретто — либреттист, норманны — норманнский, антенна — антеннщик, ванна — ваннщица, Дарданеллы — дар-данелльский, Калькутта — калькуттский, Канн (и Канны) — каннский, Равенна — равеннцы.

Однако вместо двойной согласной пишется одна согласная буква в следующих случаях: 1) в уменьшительных и фамильярных формах личных имен с суффиксом -к(а), напр.: Алла — Алка, Стелла — Стелка, Эмма — Эмка, Жанна — Жанка, Инна — Инка, Римма — Римка, Васса — Васка, Мирра — Мирка, Мариэтта — Мариэтка, Савва — Савка, Кирилл — Кирилка, Филипп — Филипка (так же: Филипок, род. п. Филипка и Филипчик); 2) одиночная буква н — в любых словах с суффиксом -к(а), напр.: финка (ср. финн), пятитонка, трёхтонка (тонна), колонка (колонна), антенка (антенна); 3) в следующих словах: кристальный (кристалл), финский (финн), оперетка (оперетта).

Примечание. В ласкательных формах имен на -очка, -ушка (Жанночка, Аллочка, Филиппушка, Кириллушка и т. п.) двойные согласные сохраняются.

Answer (score 1):

А правда, почему?

Я навскидку могу предложить только одно объяснение. 
Удвоенные согласные в русском языке обычно возникают между гласными или (совсем редко) в конце слова. Есть, разумеется, большой ряд исключений, но они все связаны с удвоением на границе морфем (корня и суффикса или приставки и корня), но это не наш случай. Здесь удвоенное Л - чисто корневое.

Comment: Кстати, та ситуация: "грамматика" - "грамотный"

Comment: Нет. "Грамотный" от "грамота". Оно так и заимствовано с одним М. Это понятно.
Вот если выяснится, что кристальный - заимствование, не свящанное с "кристалл", то может быть. Но вроде это все-то уже в русском Л потерялось.

Comment: *Програ**ммн**ый, пятиба**лльн**ый, редкомета**лльн**ый, га**лльск**ий.*